# asp.net and jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery

does anyone know how to use jquery modal dialog in asp.net pages?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

I've tried creating a simple aspx page, pasted code from the example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it almost works. The dialog briefly shows up and then disappears. It seems that the page is doing a postback. I'm not sure how to stop it, so that the modal dialog stays up.

Comment: It might help if you could show us the code for your ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) for modal dialogs. I've set it up to use a standard HTML input button to trigger the dialog, and then you can put a regular asp.net button or other controls inside of the hidden div.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="popupButton" OnClientClick="showModalPopup();" Text="Click me" runat="server" />
```

I would try adding "return false;" to the OnClientClick property of your Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="popupButton" OnClientClick="showModalPopup(); return false;" Text="Click me" runat="server" />
```

Or if you don't need to access the button in code-behind, simply use a standard HTML button and set it's onclick event attribute:

```
<button onclick="showModalPopup();">Click me</button>
```